# iCloud Photo Library - merge two Apple IDs together to one library stream?

Tags: icloud, photo-stream

Is there a way to use iCloud Photo Library and merge the photos on my wife's iPhone with mine? I'm willing to subscribe to the iCloud Photo Library service, but I rather one of us pay for the cloud service and not both. I've looked at Family Sharing option, but that seems to only be for iTunes Store items such as apps.

Comment: AFIK It is not possible to merge 2 AppleID

Comment: I don't want to actually merge two AppleIDs together. I just want to put the Camera Roll on two different phones (mine and my wife) into one iCloud Photo Library. This way, it doesn't matter who takes a picture on a specific day, she can create collages and albums from the iCloud Photo Library.